# Is it possible to make a recursive tree-like tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, tuples

## How to make a recursive tree-like tuple?

I have a function for **recursively** getting the value of an object's property:

```js
function getValue(obj: object, ...keys: string[]): any
```

and here is what it does given an object:

```js
const testObject = {
  hello: {
    world: "Hello world!",
    user: "Hello user!"
  },
  first: {
    second: 2
  },
  shallow: {
    deep: true
  }
}
console.log(getValue(testObject, "first")); // { second: 2 }
console.log(getValue(testObject, "hello", "world")); // Hello world!
console.log(getValue(testObject, "shallow", "deep")); // true
```

My goal is adding autocomplete into the function parameters:

```js
function getValueTyped<T extends object>(obj: T, ...keys: TreeKeys<T>): any
```

#### **Please note** that this function should be able to work with **any given object type!**

and the concept is (with the same object as above):

```js
getValueTyped<typeof testObject>(
  testObject,
  "hello", // This parameter shows as a union: ("hello" | "first" | "shallow")
  "world" // IF the previous parameter is "hello", than this one is ("world" | "user")
);
getValueTyped<typeof testObject>(
  testObject,
  "first", // This parameter shows as a union: ("hello" | "first" | "shallow")
  "second" // IF the previous parameter is "first", than this one is only "second"
);
```

While trying to solve this, I came up with a few things. The type of the `keys` argument should be a tuple with generics, something like this:

```js
type TreeKeys<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = [
  K, // The first property
  ...(K extends object ? TreeKeys<T[K], keyof T[K]> : [])
];
```

but it obviously didn't work. I think using `infer` might help, but I am not sure in how to implement this or if this is even possible.
*If this is still not possible but there is a proposal, I would like to take a look at it.*

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: This sort of thing is tricky; see the answer to the linked question for more information.  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjXl6m) is how I might approach it for the example in this question.  IntelliSense/auto-complete is a bit funky but this is the closest I can get and still have it behave the way you are suggesting.  If this doesn't meet your needs you might want to open a new question where you explicitly reference the linked question above and how the solution there doesn't work for you.  Good luck!